# OAuth 2.0 without browser

Tags: authentication, authorization, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

We are developing applications for different platforms including ones with no browser interaction support. And we have decided to emulate browser from our application. So is it ok with Facebook's TOS?

This theme have been mentioned already in this topic (the last post):
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4000896/logging-into-facebook-without-a-browser#comment4285566_4000963

By emulation of browser I mean following:

- We are getting the user login HTML form and fill it with information that user supplied. Then we are sending it.
- When we are receiving the authentication page we are asking the user to authorize the Facebook application to post messages.
- If user agrees then we are sending authentication form and then get access token.